# Как на UNIX системах можно сжать все pdf файлы в подкаталогах, при этом не создавая новых файлов а перезаписывая старые?

Tags: php, linux, pdf, скрипт, сжатие

Я погуглил команды для сжатия, но все они работаю с одним файлом, а у меня их сотни и все разбросаны по подкаталогам. И даже если извратиться и как-то подсунуть в эти команды список файлов, они при работе создают новые файлы с другим именем. А мне нужно имя сохранить, так как это документы на хостинге и ссылки станут недействительны.
Возможно написать php скрипт, но надо что-то придумывать с временем исполнения, там явно превышение будет.

Comment: странный вопрос. ну вот есть у вас `blabla.pdf`. и вы его каким-либо образом «сжали». а просмотрщики потом разберутся, что файл, оказывается, «сжат»? `создают новые файлы с другим именем` — наверно, в этих новых именах как раз и отражается факт сжатия? ну, например, `blabla.pdf.gz` или что-нибудь в этом духе.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался.
1)Создаем список всех файлов нужного типа, например пдфок.

```
find ./путь -size +300k -iname '*.pdf' > list.txt
```

2)Создаем баш скрипт, передаем ему list.txt и сжимаем в цикле:

```
#!/bin/bash
input=$1
while IFS= read -r line
do
ps2pdf -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook "$line" ./temp.pdf
mv -v ./temp.pdf "$line"
done < "$input"
```

Comment: Хм, то есть вы просто пересохранили из pdf в pdf? Не уверен, что это можно называть сжатием...

Comment: Ps2pdf уменьшает dpi, что и нужно